# desktop does not post after upgrade from Intel E2160 to Xeon 3220

Tags: boot, post, xeon

Upon upgrading my Intel E2160 cpu with a Xeon X3220, the desktop's heatsink fan would turn on momentarily but turn off without going into POST. I was wondering how I might be able to fix this.  I had tried removing RAM and hard drive as well to see if I can access the BIOS to no avail.  Cheers.

Comment: Even though both those processors support socket LGA775, the old processor has a TDP rating of 65W and the new processor is 105W. That's probably why it's not posting. Unless my assumption that you kept the same motherboard through this upgrade is not accurate(?).

Comment: Wouldn't you also need support in the motherboard firmware for the processor?

Comment: Thank you so much for bringing up the two possible issues I thought about.  The support page for my motherboard, asrock 775i65g, does not list the Xeon X3220 CPU here http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/775i945GZ/?cat=CPU , but these lists are usually not comprehensive.  And would the TDP discrepancy be resolved by a different PSU or will I need a new mobo for that as well?  I apologize for erring on the side of too little information, like not mentioning that all other components were kept as is, but I figured that would be more helpful than writing a book, which I'm wont to do.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but your motherboard's chipset (945GZ) doesn't support Xeons. Not only does the mobo's CPU compatibility list not include the Xeon X3220, it doesn't include any Xeons at all.

For confirmation, see the chipset family's [Intel data sheet](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/307502.pdf), page 15, which lists:

- Intel® CoreTM2 Duo
- Intel® Celeron 400 Series
- Intel® Pentium® 4 processor [...] in the LGA775 Land Grid Array package
- Intel® Pentium® D processor (supports 775-Land package)
- Intel® AtomTM 200 series and Intel AtomTM 300 Series (82945GC only)

No mention of Xeons.

See also [List of Intel chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets) at Wikipedia. For the 945G (the GZ is a variant) it shows: Pentium 4, Pentium D, Celeron D, Core 2 Extreme, Core 2 Duo.

Xeons have their own chipsets.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news - I hope you didn't pay very much for it.